# Disable Google keyboard shortcuts

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

I'm currently using Firefox on Ubuntu 12.10 and disabled Google keyboard shortcuts, mainly because if I wasn't typing in the right box, I would suddenly be doing weird things to my inbox. But disabling Google keyboard shortcuts didn't work. I thought it might be a script thing, but all scripts except Google Analytics are allowed to run (using NoScript).

Is there are way to completely disable these shortcuts, or customize them so that I can use them with the control or meta keys?

Comment: When you say Google, you mean Gmail?

Comment: GMail, Calendar and Reader

Comment: You can definitely disable all the Gmail keyboard shortcuts and they will stay disabled.

Comment: They don't, that's the problem I have. I've disabled them, but when I type outside a chat box by mistake, the shortcuts still do their thing

Comment: Even by turning them off from _Settings_ → _General_ → _Keyboard shortcuts off_ → _Save Changes_?

Comment: That's where I'm doing it. Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, by pressing **?** in the _Inbox_ view and then _Enable/Disable_ in the overlay.

Comment: You were right! For some reason, it showed 'Enabled' there. Disabling it like that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved (by Alex, see comments above): press **?** in Inbox view and enable/disable keyboard shortcuts there.